# PAM: How can I create a service which passes username/password to a script?

Tags: linux, authentication, openvpn, pam, shell-scripting

I'm setting up a PAM service for OpenVPN, such that the OpenVPN PAM module can authenticate a username/password to an external service that I will implement using a shell script.

The OpenVPN PAM module states approximately the following documentation:

> plugin openvpn-auth-pam.so "openvpn
>   name USERNAME password PASSWORD"
>
> While "USERNAME" and "PASSWORD" are
>   special strings which substitute to
>   client-supplied values, it is also
>   possible to name literal values to use
>   as PAM module query responses.  For
>   example, suppose that the login module
>   queried for a third parameter,
>   "domain" which is to be answered with
>   the constant value "mydomain.com":

So now I created an openvpn PAM configuration in /etc/pam.d/openvpn:

```
auth required pam_exec.so expose_authtok /tmp/outputenv
```

Which got me as far as executing a script and getting the password from stdin, brilliant, I'm 95% of the way there. But I don't have access to the username. I've checked the environment variables and anything I can think of, but I can't work out how I could pass BOTH the username AND password to my script for external authentication.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you not just do this using the connect-script of the openvpn config, and pass the username/password environment variables to your script, and thereby skip pam entirely ? that what we did to check windows domain users

Comment: Great question, but the authentication process in question takes 3-5 seconds to complete, and the authentication script your asking about blocks all other processes, including traffic during execution. A point clearly made in the book OpenVPN 2 Cookbook. All articles recommend using the PAM module as it handles this in a properly multi-threaded fashion.

Comment: by the way when you say it blocks traffic, do you mean all traffic, or just traffic to this user ?

Answer (score 1):

The full answer to this question is posted here:

https://forums.openvpn.net/post13002.html#p13002

Basically the example in the PAM module documentation for openvpn leads you astray here, it uses:

```
plugin openvpn-auth-pam.so "login login USERNAME password PASSWORD"
```

But the correct configuration for openvpn's server.config is:

```
plugin /usr/local/openvpn/sbin/openvpn-auth-pam.so "openvpn"
```

If you include the extra parameters shown in the documentation example it will never write out PAM_USER to the environment variables as is expected based on the documentation of pam_exec.so.